# Android different Ontouchlistener's is not working at the same time

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

This will be a remoting Touchpad application . I implemented 3 ontouchlisteners and they are touchpad , leftclick and rightclick but these listeners are not working at the same time . For example when I try to do remote touchpad leftclick or right click button is not working . Or when I click to the leftbutton the others are not working . Here are the codes I couldn't find the answer how to solve this issue .

```
fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.TouchPad);
        fl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                return Mouse(ev);
            }
        });

        fl = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.LeftButton);
        fl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                return LeftClick(ev);
            }
        });

        fl = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.RightButton);
        fl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                return RightClick(ev);
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Use individual FrameLayout object for each FrameLayout.

```
fl = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.TouchPad);
        fl.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                return Mouse(ev);
            }
        });

        f2 = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.LeftButton);
        f2.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                return LeftClick(ev);
            }
        });

        f3 = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.RightButton);
        f3.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent ev) {
                return RightClick(ev);
            }
        });
```

Comment: I already did it and it's not working . I guess its about multitouch .

Comment: Are your FrameLayouts one above the other (Z axis)?

Comment: Nope , they are not .